# Symfony, Fos User Bundle, link to auth/login

Tags: symfony, bundle

Maybe it's very silly question but how i can make link to my main page, login site (auth/login) from for example '/auth/resetting/check-email'. Im using Fos User Bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside these [files](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/config/routing) you will find every public route that is being used.

You can then use those route names to create the url.

Since this is an official repository these files are also present in your project.